# in app purchase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchases

Пришло время использовать in app purchase в проекте, начал смотреть туториал у Рея и кучу других туториалов, но к сожалению ни как не получается осуществить покупку, щас опишу весь процесс: 
1. Для начала создал в developer apple com создал для проекта сертификат App IDs. (BundleId как в Xcode )
2. Затем "пошел" в itunes Connect apple com, создал приложение по этому идентифайеру, как положено. 
3. В itunes Connect в этом проекте зашел во вкладку функции, создал встроенную покупку (Consumable - расходуемая покупка)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видите у этой встроенной покупки `id product = ru.diit.testbuygolds.` 
Дальше идем в Xcode и связываем проект с этой встроенной покупкой. Я меня есть только один класс `ViewController` вся логика находится внутри него, поэтому я скину только его.

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

var product_id: String?

@IBOutlet weak var buy100Gold: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    product_id = "ru.diit.testbuygolds"

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

    //Check if product is purchased
    if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchased")){

        // Hide ads
        //adView.hidden = true

    } else {
        print("Should show ads...")

    }

}

@IBAction func buy100GoldAction(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("About to fetch the product...")

    // Can make payments
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
        print("Fetching Products");
    }else{
        print("Can't make purchases");
    }
}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);

}

func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    response.invalidProductIdentifiers
    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            print(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(product: validProduct);
        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}


func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error Fetching product information");
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                  updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])

{
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                // Handle the purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                //adView.hidden = true
                break;
            case .failed:
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;



            case .restored:
                print("Already Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

                // Handle the purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                //adView.hidden = true
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. информацию о налогах надо заполнить
2. отправить приложение с покупками на проверку